# Dataset for musical Instruments recognition

Tags: deep-learning, keras, dataset, data, audio-recognition

I am looking for a "rich" Dataset to Teach my model to seperate Music intruments .. any Suggestion ? I found the URMP Dataset but it doesn't have many files.. I appreciate your help 
thanks and happy new year

Comment: https://github.com/cosmir/openmic-2018 is a good starting point.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question